# Is this Eaton breaker compatible with my Siemens panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I recently had a [Siemens SN4040B1200P1 panel](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/us/Catalog/Product/?mlfb=US2%3aSN4040B1200) installed to replace/upgrade a small panel in my garage.

The electrician who did the work was considerate enough to pick up a 2-pole breaker and split out the MWBC that I'd combined because the old panel was full. I just realized, though, that he put an Eaton BR220 breaker in there instead of a Siemens.

[image: Image of Eaton Type BR220 2-pole breaker]

Here's the appropriate labeling on the panel:

[image: Image of Siemens panel label]

Is this breaker compatible with my panel?

---

Note: I have reviewed the suggested duplicate and included an image of the labeling in my panel. However, it took quite a bit more research than simply looking at the label (as suggested by answers to the other question) to determine that this breaker is *close* but is *NOT* a match for my panel. Therefore, while the other question provided a good direction, it does not provide the actual answer to my question.

Comment: Eaton *says* they're designed and tested to be compatible.

Comment: Well, that, along with a link, @Huesmann would be an answer.

Comment: Have you done *any* research at all before posting? I find it hard to believe you’re not aware this topic has been covered here extensively already.

Comment: For example: [What brand of circuit breakers can I use in my panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/265909/what-brand-of-circuit-breakers-can-i-use-in-my-panel)

Comment: @FreeMan this is literally the first link when I Google "are eaton breakers compatible with siemens" https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/electrical-circuit-protection/classified-circuit-breakers.html

Comment: @nobody yes, I did do research. I've looked through both Siemens & Eaton web sites looking for info on this and none of them were particularly explicit.

Comment: @Huesmann that says they're "classified", but it doesn't say what panels they're classified for. Am I missing something?

Comment: From @huesmann's link "These breakers are classified as direct replacements by Underwriters Laboratories." "Eaton's UL-classified breakers are designed and tested to be both mechanically and electrically interchangeable with circuit breakers manufactured by General Electric, Thomas & Betts, ITE/Siemens, Murray, Crouse-Hinds and Square D."

Comment: Thanks, @FredricShope, however "Eaton UL-classified replacement circuit breakers are available in both 3/4-inch **Type CHQ** and 1-inch **Type CL**, single- and two-pole configurations." However, mine is a **Type BR** and **Type C** which, to me, appear to be different - am I wrong in this understanding?

Comment: Confusion here is 100% understandable. Just as QP is on the label and on the breakers but Siemens catalog part #s just have Q, you *might* wonder whether CL and C are the same thing. They aren't, as it turns out, but only thorough research can determine the correct answers. Which the electrician clearly didn't do :-)

Comment: @FreeMan You have a silver badge in “electrical” and you participated in the question I linked, which is an exact duplicate of this question. It took less than five seconds to find by searching this site for “qp br”.

Answer (score 3):

Eaton has **UL Classified** breakers which are legal and safe to use as replacements for certain other brands of breakers. From the [Eaton catalog](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/low-voltage-power-distribution-controls-systems/loadcenters-and-circuit-breakers-v1-t1-ca08100002e.pdf), page 103, we have:

> Type CL Replacement Breakers for Square D HOMELINE, General Electric, Crouse-Hinds, Thomas & Betts, Murray and ITE®/Siemens Loadcenters
>
> 20 #14–4 CL120 CL220

So the CL220 is a replacement. Now to confirm, we have this [very handy page](https://colonialelectricsupply.com/ss-20/eaton-20/pdfs/classified-circuit-breakers.pdf)  which includes a chart showing that the CL220 is a classified replacement for the Siemens *Catalog Number* Q220.

But wait, there's more. The panel label says QP (and others) but not Q. From [this poorly scanned catalog page at Home Depot](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/c1/c1539716-6a50-42ef-bbb7-34f6e6171421.pdf) we see that the Q220 catalog number is in fact a QP breaker.

So now we know that Eaton makes a breaker you can use in this panel.

But is this the right one?

**NO!**

The BR220/C220 and the CL220 are two *different* Eaton products. They are both double 20A 1" breakers. But they are different product lines.

So your "electrician" got a bit confused or has a bad case of wishful thinking. In a quick search, Home Depot does not currently stock the CL220, but many other places do, typically for just a few dollars more than the BR220.

**TL;DR No. Replace it with a genuine Siemens Q220 or with the properly Classified Eaton CL220.**

Comment: Thank you! I tried searching for this type of info, but came up short.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be "No".

According to the label on the panel itself:

[image: image of panel labeling]

There is no `BR` type breaker that's approved for use in this panel.

Comment: That’s not how classification works.

Comment: Nor the alternate C type, since that breaker has two types (which I think is "Challenger" replacements.) How some folks get or keep an electrician's license is a mystery at times...(I had a guy licensed in 3 states in for my service install. He stripped Romex and put the unmarked wires in conduit...)

Comment: Well, instead of telling me that I'm just stupid, @nobody, how about educating me so I can stop asking stupid questions. That would actually be helpful instead of snarky and holier-than-thou.

Comment: Welcome to DIY SE. The label does not tell us the answer. But the label *does* tell us useful information to help answer. Please edit the panel image into the original question. And see the [Tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about how to use DIY SE. :-)